# Refresh content/page on the hour every hour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code that is meant to refresh the page on the hour, every hour but it doesn't seem to execute...

This is the code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

$date = date("i:s");

list($cur_min, $cur_sec) = explode(':', $date);

$mins_left = ($cur_min == 59) ? 0 : 60 - $cur_min;
$secs_left = 60 - $cur_sec;

$time=($mins_left*60+$secs_left)*1000;

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("refresh()",<?php echo $time; ?>);
function refresh(){
    window.location = location.href;
}
</script>
```

I need it to run off the server clock too and not from when the user lands on the page.

Idealy, would be awesome if it could just refresh the content of every div labeled with the class named "locality"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use DateTime in PHP and for easy convertion use timestamps.

```
$date = new \DateTime(strtotime(time()), new \DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney")));
$date->add(new \DateInterval('PT1H'));
$time = $date->format('U') % 3600;
```

And for JS:

```
var time = (Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) % 3600);
if(time > <?= $time ?>){
  var rtime = time - <?= $time ?>;
} else {
  var rtime = <?= $time ?> - time; 
}

setInterval(function(){
  window.location.reload(1);
},rtime * 1000);
```

But im not sure why:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

Will not suffice as it will just refresh an hour later (and so on) of when the user enters the page, doesn't really matter what timezone.

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks @Xorifelse!
I need the content to load on the hour as new content is generated every 60 minutes... Wouldn't the meta refresh start from when they land, so if they landed at 3:23, it would refresh at 4:23?

Comment: Yes it would, but much simpler. The code is too reliant of the client to have a correct time. But I woke up and read the code and I saw a very simple way to almost fully fix that issue: Modulo! As that will also fix the issue with more than 1 hour time differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the JavaScript part:

```js
function refresh(){
    window.location.reload();
}
setTimeout(refresh, <?php echo $time; ?>);
```

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but I tried a few changes:

- [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) is more explicit than `window.location = location.href` (which, by the way, could be simplified to `window.location = window.location`)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) because if the refreshing fails again for some reason, you don't want to try refreshing again in
- put the `setTimeout` call after the definition of the function to be sure that there isn't a problem with the function not being defined yet

Try it. If that code still doesn't work for you, try looking at your generated HTML and seeing what value for `$time` was printed. Also check the browser console for any errors.

By the way, the code would be clearer if you renamed the variable `$time` to `$ms_until_start_of_hour`.